# How to identify the most recent file in a Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a folder in Google drive in to which files are regularly dumped from a reporting tool. The files are in .xls format. They all have the same name and I want to identify the most recent file so that I can import the data in to a Google sheet.

As you will be able to tell from the below I am new to Google Apps script. I have been trying to catch the various files from the file iterator into an array to run a Math.max function on the result to end up with just one value. Of course, once I have identified the newest date I also need to return the fileID associated with - but I haven't got that far yet. I am probably heading in the completely wrong direction so any tips/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
function listLatestFile(id) {
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("GmailAttachments");
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('mrp_out.xlsx');
while (files.hasNext()) {
 var file = files.next();
 var date = (1 - file.getDateCreated());
 var datediff = new Array(date);
 var datelast = Math.max(datediff);
 Logger.log(datelast);
 } 
//Logger.log(date);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were not very far from the solution... I tried using a slightly different approach : I store all dates and IDs in an 2D array, I sort the array and retrieve the first element (after sorting) in the 2cond dimension to return the file ID.

code :

```
function listLatestFile() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("GmailAttachments");
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('mrp_out.xlsx');
  var result = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    result.push([file.getDateCreated(),file.getId()]);
 } 
  Logger.log(result);
  var id = result.sort()[0][1];
  Logger.log(id);
  return id;// return most recent file ID
};
```

**EDIT :** if you want to have more control on the sorting method, you can use a more "sophisticated" sort method like below :

```
   ...// same as above
  result.sort(function(x,y){
    var xp = x[0];// get first element in inner array
    var yp = y[0];
    return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;// choose the sort order
  });    
  var id = result[0][1];
  Logger.log(id);
  return id;
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that Serge. I was happy to see that I was conceptually heading in the right direction (pity about the execution).

Do you have any thoughts on how I could add some functionality to the existing code to compare the newest ID to the existing ID's and delete the ID's that don't match. I know how to trash them I just don't know how I would do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted above didn't work for me, so I came up with my own solution, which works.

Obviously (**in late 2017**) google drive sorts the files. So the last created file is the first in the iterator.

Here's the code to get the latest file ID :

```
 function getLatestFileId(){

   var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Aff Comm");
   var files = folder.next().getFiles();
   var lastFileId = files.next().getId();


   return lastFileId.toString();

}
```