# Get the URL of the last item added to a folder

Tags: python, google-drive-api

So I have a script which uploads a file to a specific folder. I want to get URL of the most recently uploaded item in that folder? How would I accomplish this in as simple a manner is possibly.

For example, say I have a folder called "Photos", and I want to retrieve the latest item that was uploaded to that folder and display it somewhere. How can I get that URL? You may assume "Photos" is a shared folder.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add the context of your question in the text, not just as tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so via your script. Just first retrieve the file with the **most recent** `getDateCreated()` then retrieve the URL with `getUrl()`. Descriptions of the two from the docs:

`getDateCreated()`

> Gets the date the File was created.

`getUrl()`

> Gets the URL that can be used to open the File in a Google App like Drive or Docs.

Found these posts on how to retrieve the most recent file in a Drive folder:

- [How to identify the most recent file in a Google Drive folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989559/how-to-identify-the-most-recent-file-in-a-google-drive-folder)
- [Get the Newest File in a Google Drive Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323703/get-the-newest-file-in-a-google-drive-folder)

Answer (score 0):

- Hash the file names, stored the last file name into database
- Rename the file names using timestamp